# About backing field type in C# 6

Tags: c#

In C# 6, we can assign in-line values to automatic property. Since the value of these automatic property is set directly to the backing field (without setter), can I assume the backing field is a 'static type'? If I am wrong, can someone explain me how value is been assigned to backing field? At which stage compiler assign the in-line to the Property ?

```
class ProDemo 
{            
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Jon";
}
```

Can someone explain me how automatic property implemented differently in C# 6 while comparing previous version of C#?

Comment: why did the author get -3 votes?

Comment: Use ILSpy it will help you understand how compiler changes the code behind the scenes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
class ProDemo 
{            
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Jon";
}
```

Is compiled to this:

```
class ProDemo 
{        
    private string _name = "Jon";
    public string get_Name() { return _name; }
    public void set_Name(string value) { _name = value; }
}
```

There isn't anything to do with static types, at all.

Comment: Ok. In that case, why following assignment doesn't work                        private string anotherInstaceName = "Jon";
        //A field initializer cannot reference a non static field
        public string Name { get; set; } = anotherInstaceName;

Comment: As per the documentation, it doesn't set such in-line assignment through setters.

Comment: @Nair It doesn't work for exactly the same reason it wouldn't work in this answer's second snippet, which is what it's conceptually transformed into.  Try doing the same thing with a field initializer and it fails for exactly the same reason.

Comment: @Servy, Much appreciate your version. I am aware of how this is implemented internally in the past. But, what I am trying to understand is, how this is different in c# 6.0 to facilitate as in-line assignment.

Comment: @Servy, If I assume your point as valid then  why we couldn't do in-line assignment in the past?

Comment: Nothing changed with respect to how fields are initialized.  You can simply initialize the field now.  Your invalid initializer is just as invalid for a field as it is for an automatically implemented property, and for *exactly* the same reason, as the code samples in the answer show.

Comment: @Nair the *only* thing that has changed is that C# now emits two instructions when assigning a default value to a property. Those two instructions are `IL_0001:  ldstr       "Jon"` and `IL_0006:  stfld`. Before `C#6`, it would be equivalent to `private string _name;` instead of `private string _name  = "Jon";`. The ***only*** difference is the initialization of the backing field, nothing else.